Manhwa where the Female lead can see ghosts
I read a manhwa about a year ago that I do not remember well but I do believe it took place in a fantasy historical setting.
I remember the female lead had blue eyes with light brown hair, and the male lead had light blue hair. The female lead possessed special powers and could see ghosts, one of the ghosts was the founding emperor and he had a relationship with a saint or goddess. The main lead's first encounter happened at night when the female lead intercepted the male lead's carriage, disguising herself as an old lady. She told him she would send her granddaughter to meet with him, but in reality, she was that granddaughter, hiding her identity with black hair. Later on, an event occurred where she almost died.

You could improve this Anime Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. "She had powers" is incredibly vague

This is Secret Lady. It is licensed by Tapas.

Lady Rosentine Arzen was born with the ability to see ghosts, an offense punishable by death under imperial law, and something which threatens to ruin her family. So when Rosentine learns of a plot to poison the imperials, she goes undercover as a vagabond sorcerer to save Prince Charteris Kartazen, who promises to protect her family should she solve the mystery. But who would want to harm the prince? The palace teems with danger, but it’s Rosentine’s own secret that could prove fatal to her.

The synopsis covers the ability to see ghosts. I don't recall the specifics of any of the ghosts she talks to, but she visits many that live in the palace and know numerous secrets.
The carriage scene is in chapter 5 and 6. She puts on a heavy cloak in the middle of the night and jumps in front of the prince's carriage. When he sees her, she offers to use her sorcery powers to help him survive an assassination attempt. She offers to have her granddaughter meet him later to better plan for the threats to his life.

She has blonde hair, but uses a black wig as a disguise.

